# Identify color in matlab

Tags: matlab, rgb, color-space, hsv

I want to identify the colors of [this color checker chart](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/38236/1/Color_Checker_Chart.png) in a little robust way. In the first step not every color has to be detected correctly.

I ectracted already the subimages, so that I have squares with only one color.

The idea for detecting the color (and print them out) was to transform the colors from RGB to the HSV color model.

Does anybody has a better solution or can help?
Best regards!

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about the colors?  The colloquial names ie 'approximately brown', or something else?

Comment: yes excactly. In the first step "brown" would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want an algorithm like the following:

- Compute the mean RGB value for a given subimg.
- Compute the Euclidean distance from your mean RGB value to the RGB value in each of the
  squares.
- Return the square name that is closest to your RGB value.

Comment: Beat me too it.  I would also add, that there is no point in keep an entire swath of the color palette around.  Single pixels will work for your comparison.